# bash Implementing parallel chunk download using curl and mimic aria2 functionality

Tags: bash, curl, wget

For large file download, aria2 supports -x 16 -s 32, options that are for multithreaded multichunk download.

**Using python asyncio we can do this, by getting file size, and creating chunk parts from file size and parallel request each chunk to temp file and join them**

**Can same be done using curl/wget + bash +xargs/parallel utilities**

Using

1. curl head request and get total size
2. create chunk ranges
3. curl --range option to download each chunk in parallel **(In latest curl -Z support parallel, or in old curl, use xargs -P or gnu parallel -J options)**
4. combine all parts

Can anyone help with creating bash function with **failsafe - error handling and retry in case of sever load and empty chunk or temporary ip ban to ise while True loop until file has been succesfully downloaded**

**Can someone explain:  in case of idm and aria2 like tools i have read that they downlaod by creating multiple connections to server how -x 16 and -s 32 options work.
how creating multiple connection works for multithreaded parallel downloafing and how can we implememy it with curl + bash**

Comment: Naira, I've already advised you that we are not a free script-writing service, and recommended you take the [tour] to see what's [on topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here

Comment: Look at https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-keep-order-of-output-same-as-order-of-input (last paragraph)